# how toUpdate MySQL table using imploded array in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a MySQL table using an imploded array in PHP but I am unable to achieve my goal.

Here is my code

**retrive.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","helixdemo");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$id=1;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM employee
    WHERE id='1'");

$focus = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $focus=explode(",",$row['name']);
?>
<?php
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="update1.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="shakti">
<input type="text" name="name" value="shakti">
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Item 1"  <?php if(in_array("Item 1",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>/>Item 1
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Item 2"  <?php if(in_array("Item 2",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>/>Item 2
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Item 3"  <?php if(in_array("Item 3",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> />Item 3
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Item 4" />Item 4
<input type="checkbox" name="cbox[]" value="Item 5" />Item 5

<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

**update.php**

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","HelixDemo");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$items = implode(",",$_REQUEST['cbox']);
$sql = ('UPDATE employee
    SET name = '.$items.'
    WHERE id;');


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo " record added";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**I am getting the following error**

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1,Item 2 WHERE id' at line 2

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Strings need to be quoted (yours is not). But putting a comma-separated list of values into one column is generally a sign of poor db design, so you may want to rethink what you're doing. You also don't have a proper `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `UPDATE employee
SET name = '.$items.'
WHERE id;` - aren't you missing something at the end of your query

Comment: `$focus=explode(",",$row['name']); $check = implode(',' , $focus);` What's going on here?

Comment: @juergen what i am missing here

Comment: a lot is missing, like: quotes, the end of the where statement, sql injection prevention, proper error handling, a config file, indentation and so on..

Comment: @shaktisharma: `where id = $something`

Comment: $juergen id=1  i added there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update statement is wrong

```
$sql = ('UPDATE employee SET name = '.$items.' WHERE id;');
```

should be:

```
$sql = "UPDATE employee SET name = '".$items."' WHERE id=1";
```

Please notice the single and double quotes and assignment of value to id.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60019/discussion-on-answer-by-paullo-how-toupdate-mysql-table-using-imploded-array-in).

Comment: You can check your mail now

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is quotes. You need quotes because `name` is a `VARCHAR`.

Your second problem is the id of row you're updating, you should send it too (using a hidden input ) and store it in variable `$id` for example.

And the code should be :

```
$sql = ('UPDATE employee
    SET name = \''.$items.'\'
    WHERE id = '.$id.' ;');
```

Comment: still prob is same here

Comment: there is no error message here  empty value inserting in my db